# Regular Expression to get link and link description

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I'm attempting to develop my own linking syntax as such:

```
[this is google|google.com]
```

I know how to get the text between the square brackets (`\[(.*?)\]`) but I'm not sure how to extract the individual pieces. Also, if someone wanted to simply add square brackets without a link (eg. `[this is google]`), it wouldn't be detected as a link.

Can anyone provide me with some direction on this? I need to access both pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
\[(.*?)\|(.*?)\]
```

Basically, just add another capture group. The `\|` escapes the `|` in your marvelous syntax. :)

http://regex101.com/r/dS3uJ9

Comment: Thanks! ... That's obvious now that I've seen it *shakes head in disappointment*

Answer (score 0):

You can use;

```
s='[this is google|google.com]';
m = s.match(/\[([^|]+)\|([^\]]+)\]/);
```

Then use `m[1]` and `m[2]` for description and link.

**UPDATE:** For showing difference between performances of both regex approaches I created 2 regex101 links:

1. http://regex101.com/r/xZ6nB7 (Using negation)
2. http://regex101.com/r/rI0eH8 (Using lazy quantifier `.*?`

To see performance difference click on **`Launch regex debugger`** link on top-left of both links.

You will notice my regex displays:

> +Match 1 - finished in 11 steps

But `.*?` link shows this:

> +Match 1 - finished in 59 steps

That proves point that negation based regex is much more efficient than `.*` approach.

**PS:** If you click on **`+Match 1 - finished in 59 steps`** you will see red color `BACKTRACK` messages in 2nd link.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain yours a bit? Like why you didn't use `(.*?)`?

Comment: `.*?` is non-greedy regex cannot match efficiency of negation based regex i.e. `[^|]+`

Comment: What is a negation based regex?

Comment: Negation based regex is `[^|]+` which means match 1 or more until a pipe is found. It is presence of `^` at first position inside `[ and ]` that makes it a negation.

Comment: So basically does the same as (.*?) ?

Comment: It is not same `.*?` is processed differently as it involves backtracking.

Comment: @Jeff: I have updated answer with more details on both regex approaches.

Comment: Thanks! So it basically does the exact same (captures whatever is between the before and after, lazily) except its faster?

Comment: Thats right, result will be same but faster and more efficient than lazy quantifier.

Answer (score 0):

Not this? Try this regex

```
(\[(.*?)\|?(.*?)\])
```